# access object variable from method javascript

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

i have a problem accessing an array within an object method.
While the log returns the value perfectly, the following line returns an error that allRect[n] is undefined.

I suppose it has something to do with variable accessibility, but the fact that it can be logged in one line and refuses it's existence in the next one leaves me a bit out of ideas.

Thanks all.

```
        this.s = Snap('#'+id);
        var allRects = [];

        this.xPos = 0;
        var scale = vizWidth/locationSum(data);         

        ...


        //methods
        this.updateViz = function() {

            apiRequest('datasets', 164, 'json').done(   

                function(data){ 
                    var n = 0;


                    data = locationDataIntoArray(data);


                    for(i = 0; i< allRects.length; i++){
                        console.log(allRects[n]);

                        allRects[n].animate({ width:parseInt(data[i][2]), opacity:evaluateMachine(data[i][0])},3000);
                        n++;
                        allRects[n].animate({ width:parseInt(data[i][3]), opacity:evaluateTech(data[i][1])},3000);
                        n++;                
                    }

                }       
            )
        };
```

Comment: Please clarify the two places where you are trying to access it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere else in your code, where you are referring to `allRects` as `allRect`?

Comment: the variable n is being increased twice. Is it correct?

Comment: Why does the `n` variable exist.

Comment: **`an array within an object method`?** The fact that you want to access a local array of a method, indicates that **it should not be local to begin with**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
                for(i = 0; i< allRects.length; i++){
                    console.log(allRects[n]);

                    allRects[n].animate({ width:parseInt(data[i][2]), opacity:evaluateMachine(data[i][0])},3000);
                    n++;
                    allRects[n].animate({ width:parseInt(data[i][3]), opacity:evaluateTech(data[i][1])},3000);
                    n++;                
                }
```

you're incrementing `n` **twice** on each iteration. Halfway through the `for` loop, `n` will be beyond the end of the array.

The first time through the loop, when `i` and `n` are both zero, you'll animate `allRects[0]`. Then you increment `n` and animate `allRects[1]`, and then increment `n` again. Thus, on the second time through the loop, you'll be animating `allRects[2]` and `allRects[3]`, and so on.

Comment: indeed, must have overlooked the obvious since i would have expected an out of bound exception...

Comment: @onkeldittmeyer there's no such thing as an "out-of-bounds" exception in JavaScript.